Delay on info display Android
So , Ill begin by explain the main issue. The app works as intended , this is the functions modularly work but when put together there's a break of information flow.
I have a navbar that "refreshes" the fragment . This fragments lists leagues and when those lists are clicked the classifcation league is shown. There's a weird delay that only after 2 refreshes anything is displayed , either be it the delete league , the join league , etc... So i'll just dump my code in here in hopes that someone brighter will find the mistake. Thanks in advance, if you want more specific code ask, i just thought this was the most important for the issue.
Here's the Fragment code:
package projeto.fantasyleague.fragments

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.ClipData
import android.content.ClipboardManager
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject
import projeto.fantasyleague.DashboardActivity
import projeto.fantasyleague.R
import projeto.fantasyleague.adapter.ClassificationAdapter
import projeto.fantasyleague.adapter.LeagueAdapter
import projeto.fantasyleague.model.ClassificationItem
import projeto.fantasyleague.model.League
import projeto.fantasyleague.utils.ApiConstants


class LeagueListFragment : Fragment() {
    companion object {
        lateinit var recyclerViewList : RecyclerView
        lateinit var recyclerViewClassification : RecyclerView
        val listaLigas = ArrayList<League>()
        val classification = ArrayList<ClassificationItem>()
    }



    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_league_list, container, false)
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val sharedPreferences = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("pmLogin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val currentUID = sharedPreferences.getInt("uid", -1) // Default to -1 if UID is not found
        val authToken = sharedPreferences.getString("auth_token", "")

        val inputInvitationCode: TextInputEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.input_invitation_code)
        val inputLeagueName: TextInputEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.input_league_name)
        val buttonJoinLeague: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.button_join_league)
        val buttonCreateLeague: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.button_create_league)


        // Set button click listeners
        buttonJoinLeague.setOnClickListener {
            val invitationCode = inputInvitationCode.text.toString()
            if (invitationCode.isNotEmpty()) {
                joinLeague(authToken!!, invitationCode)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter a valid invitation code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        buttonCreateLeague.setOnClickListener {
            val leagueName = inputLeagueName.text.toString()
            if (leagueName.isNotEmpty()) {
                createLeague(authToken!!, leagueName, )
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter a league name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }





        recyclerViewList = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_leagues)
        recyclerViewList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)


        recyclerViewClassification = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_classification)
        recyclerViewClassification.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)


        if (!authToken.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            fetchLeagues(authToken)
            // After leagues are fetched, notify the adapter
            recyclerViewList.adapter = LeagueAdapter(
                listaLigas,
                currentUID,
                onClipboardClick = { invitationCode ->
                    val clipboardManager = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
                    val clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Invitation Code", invitationCode)
                    clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clip)
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Invitation code copied to clipboard!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                },
                onTrashClick = { leagueId ->
                    deleteLeague(authToken, leagueId)

                },
                onLeagueClick = { leagueId ->
                    fetchClassification(authToken, leagueId)

                }
            )

            recyclerViewList.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            if (listaLigas.isNotEmpty()) {
                fetchClassification(authToken, listaLigas[0].id)
                recyclerViewClassification.adapter = ClassificationAdapter(classification, currentUID)
                recyclerViewClassification.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

        }











    }

    private fun deleteLeague(authToken: String, leagueId: Int) {
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(requireContext())
        val url = ApiConstants.DELETE_LEAGUE
        val requestBody = JSONObject().apply {
            put("leagueId", leagueId)
        }

        val jsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(
            Method.POST, url, requestBody,
            { response ->
                try {
                    if (response.getBoolean("success")) {
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "League deleted successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        fetchLeagues(authToken)
                        recyclerViewList.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Failed to delete league.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    Log.e("LeagueListFragment", "Error parsing response: ${e.message}")
                }
            },
            { error ->
                Log.e("LeagueListFragment", "Error deleting league: ${error.networkResponse?.statusCode} - ${error.message}")
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Error deleting league ${error.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        ) {
            override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $authToken"
                headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
                headers["Action"] = "DELETE"
                return headers
            }
        }

        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
    }


    private fun joinLeague(authToken: String, invitationCode: String) {
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(requireContext())
        val url = ApiConstants.JOIN_LEAGUE

        val requestBody = JSONObject().apply {
            put("invitationCode", invitationCode)

        }

        val jsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(
            Method.POST, url, requestBody,
            { response ->
                try {
                    if (response.getBoolean("success")) {
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Successfully joined the league!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        fetchLeagues(authToken) // Refresh the list of leagues after joining
                        recyclerViewList.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Failed to join the league.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    Log.e("LeagueListFragment", "Error parsing response: ${e.message}")
                }
            },
            { error ->
                Log.e("LeagueListFragment", "Error joining league: ${error.networkResponse?.statusCode} - ${error.message}")
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Error joining league", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        ) {
            override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $authToken"
                headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
                return headers
            }
        }

        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
    }


    private fun createLeague(authToken: String, leagueName: String) {
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(requireContext())
        val url = ApiConstants.CREATE_LEAGUE

        val requestBody = JSONObject().apply {
            put("leaguename", leagueName)

        }

        val jsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(
            Method.POST, url, requestBody,
            { response ->
                try {
                    if (response.getBoolean("success")) {
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "League created successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        fetchLeagues(authToken) // Refresh the list of leagues after creation
                        recyclerViewList.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Failed to create league.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    Log.e("LeagueListFragment", "Error parsing response: ${e.message}")
                }
            },
            { error ->
                Log.e("LeagueListFragment", "Error creating league: ${error.networkResponse?.statusCode} - ${error.message}")
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Error creating league", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        ) {
            override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $authToken"
                headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
                headers["Action"] = "POST"
                return headers
            }
        }

        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
    }


    private fun fetchLeagues(authToken: String) {
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(requireContext())
        val url = ApiConstants.FETCH_LEAGUES
        val jsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(
            Method.GET, url, null,
            { response ->
                try {
                    val leaguesArray = response.getJSONArray("leagues")
                    listaLigas.clear()
                    listaLigas.add(League(name = "Global League"))
                    for (i in 0 until leaguesArray.length()) {
                        val leagueObject = leaguesArray.getJSONObject(i)
                        val league = League(
                            id = leagueObject.getInt("LeagueID"),
                            name = leagueObject.getString("leaguename"),
                            ownerId = leagueObject.getInt("HostID"),
                            invitationCode = leagueObject.getString("invitationCode")
                        )
                        listaLigas.add(league)
                    }

                    Log.d("LeagueListFragment", "Leagues fetched successfully. Count: ${listaLigas.size}")
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    Log.e("LeagueListFragment", "Error parsing leagues JSON: ${e.message}")
                }
            },
            { error ->
                Log.e("LeagueListFragment", "Error fetching leagues: ${error.networkResponse?.statusCode} - ${error.message}")
            }
        ) {
            override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $authToken"
                headers["Action"] = "GET"
                headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
                return headers
            }
        }

        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
    }

    private fun fetchClassification(authToken: String, leagueId: Int) {
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(requireContext())
        var url = ""
        val requestBody: JSONObject?
        if(leagueId == -1){
            url = ApiConstants.GENERAL_CLASSIFICATION
            requestBody = null
        }else{
            url = ApiConstants.CLASSIFICATION
            requestBody = JSONObject().apply {
                put("leagueId", leagueId)
            }
        }

        val jsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(
            Method.GET, url, requestBody,
            { response ->
                try {
                    val classificationArray = response.getJSONArray("classification")
                    classification.clear()


                    for (i in 0 until classificationArray.length()) {
                        val classificationObject = classificationArray.getJSONObject(i)
                        val item = ClassificationItem(
                            rank = i + 1,
                            teamName = classificationObject.getString("teamname"),
                            teamID = classificationObject.getInt("TeamID"),
                            ownerID = classificationObject.getInt("userID"),
                            userName = classificationObject.getString("username"),
                            points = classificationObject.optString("totalPoints","0")
                        )
                        classification.add(item)
                    }

                    Log.d("LeagueListFragment", "Classification fetched successfully. Count: ${classification.size}")
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    Log.e("LeagueListFragment", "Error parsing classification JSON: ${e.message}")
                }
            },
            { error ->
                Log.e("LeagueListFragment", "Error fetching classification: ${error.networkResponse?.statusCode} - ${error.message}")
            }
        ) {
            override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $authToken"
                headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
                headers["Action"] = "GET"
                return headers
            }
        }

        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)

    }




}

List Leagues adapter
package projeto.fantasyleague.adapter

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import projeto.fantasyleague.R
import projeto.fantasyleague.model.League







class LeagueAdapter(
    private val leagues: ArrayList<League>,
    private val currentUserId: Int,
    private val onClipboardClick: (String) -> Unit,
    private val onTrashClick: (Int) -> Unit,
    private val onLeagueClick: (Int) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<LeagueAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val leagueName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_league_name)
        val iconCrown: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_crown)
        val iconClipboard: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_clipboard)
        val iconTrash: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_trash)
        val card: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardLeague)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_league, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val league = leagues[position]
        holder.leagueName.text = league.name

        holder.card.setOnClickListener {
            onLeagueClick(league.id)
        }

        if (league.id == -1) {
            holder.card.setCardBackgroundColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(holder.card.context, R.color.ocean_blue)
            )
        }

        // Show icons only for league owners
        if (league.ownerId == currentUserId) {
            holder.iconCrown.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.iconClipboard.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.iconTrash.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            // Set click listeners
            holder.iconClipboard.setOnClickListener {
                onClipboardClick(league.invitationCode)
            }

            holder.iconTrash.setOnClickListener {
                onTrashClick(league.id)
            }
        } else {
            holder.iconCrown.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.iconClipboard.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.iconTrash.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = leagues.size
}


Classification Adapter
package projeto.fantasyleague.adapter



import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import projeto.fantasyleague.R
import projeto.fantasyleague.databinding.ItemClassificationBinding
import projeto.fantasyleague.model.ClassificationItem


class ClassificationAdapter(private val items: ArrayList<ClassificationItem>,private val currentUserId: Int) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ClassificationAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    // ViewHolder to hold the views
    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val txtRank: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_rank)
        val txtTeamName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_team_name)
        val txtUserName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_user_name)
        val txtPoints: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_points)
        val card: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.classCard)

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_classification, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }


    // Bind the data to the ViewHolder
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Log.d("Adapter", "Binding data for position: $position")

        val classif = items[position]
        holder.txtRank.text = classif.rank.toString()
        holder.txtTeamName.text = classif.teamName
        holder.txtUserName.text = classif.userName
        holder.txtPoints.text = classif.points.toString()

        val rank = classif.rank
        // Use a when statement to set the background color based on rank
        val colorRes = when (rank) {
            1 -> R.color.gold
            2 -> R.color.silver
            3 -> R.color.bronze
            else -> R.color.white // Optional default color for ranks other than 1, 2, or 3
        }

        holder.card.setCardBackgroundColor(
            ContextCompat.getColor(holder.card.context, colorRes)
        )

    }

    // Return the total number of items in the list
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }
}

DashboardActivity
class DashboardActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val binding by lazy {
        ActivityDashboardBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    }



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(binding.root)
        val nav = binding.navbar

        // Set click listeners for navbar items
        nav.navTrophy.setOnClickListener{
            binding.fragmentContainer.removeAllViews()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Trophy clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        nav.navLeagues.setOnClickListener{
            binding.fragmentContainer.removeAllViews()
            supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, LeagueListFragment())
                .commit()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Leagues clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        nav.navTeam.setOnClickListener{
            binding.fragmentContainer.removeAllViews()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Team clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }





    }
}
````
Sorry about the dump!


Adapter is not notified, of the data changes. I recommend instead of using the RecyclerViewAdapter to use ListAdapter<T,VH>

Tried it , same problem. Thanks anyway

With your current implementation, whenever updating data on adapter, call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()
